# j2me polish binary compatibility

Tags: j2mepolish, binary-compatibility

Is it possible using j2me polish to have only one jar file that run across multiple handset ?

basically we want to have binary compatibility, and don't want different build for different handset, at the same time we needs to have good ui

we do have 3 optino 1. lwuit, 2. polish 3. custom development  and we wanted to go with polish, but initial hack shown, we need to build it for separate device.

any clue/pointer?

raxit

Answer (score 1):

A lot of polish is based around using the preprocessor to do different things, so you'd be losing a lot of what it does.

It certainly is possible to do a lot of things at runtime, on the OrangePixel site theres some nice code for getting softkey events off different phones (might need some tweaking).

It's possible to do a lot of stuff at runtime, but it will be painful ... welcome to j2me !